# Finding the percentage of observations that differ from the mean by some amount for the normal distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, continuity, normal-distribution

I was trying to solve the following problem:

If a set of observations is normally distributed, what percent of these differ from the mean by:

a) more than $1.3\sigma $

b) less than $0.52\sigma $

I wrote $P(X-\mu <1.3\sigma \cup  \mu -X <1.3\sigma)$ to solve  a) however, trying to do the same for b):
$$P(X-\mu >0.52\sigma \cup  \mu -X >0.52\sigma)$$
yields $1$, which makes sense when graphing both inequalities on the same line, but this doesn't agree with the actual solution to problem and I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: Should it be $1.3 \sigma$ rather than $1.3 \sigma^2$? (Same for (b).)

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would say that instead of computing how many observations differ from the mean by **more** than $1.3 \sigma$ you are computing how many differ by **less** than that value, that is, you are counting the internal values instead of the external ones.

In other words, if you look at this image:

[image: standard normal pdf]

you are integrating the darker part, instead of integrating outside it.

I would rewrite your expression as $P\Big(\frac{|X-\mu|}{\sigma} > 1.3 \sigma\Big)$ and than use the normal table to compute it.

In general, letting $\phi(z)$ be the standard normal probability function (i.e., it gives you the integral of the pdf from $- \infty$ to $z$) and $Z$ a normalized gaussian distribution (in your case $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$) you can compute your probabilities as $P(|Z|>z) = 2(1-\phi(z))$.

If I'm not wrong in substituting the values, I obtain for:

- more than $1.3\sigma$, 0.1936
- more than $0.52\sigma$, 0.603

If instead we want to compute $P(|Z| < z) = \phi(z) - \phi(-z) = 2\phi(z) - 1$ where the last comes from the fact that $\phi(-z) = 1 - \phi(z)$.

Using this formula I get for:

- less than $0.52\sigma$, 0.397

The best way to understand these calculations is to visualize what you are doing: the probabilities are the areas that you consider and, then, you are just summing and subtracting among areas to get what you want. To be more specific, in this case I get the whole area of the pdf from $-\infty$ to $z$ using $\phi(z)$ and than subtract the area from $-\infty$ to $-z$ using $\phi(-z)$ so that you are keeping only values between $-z$ and $z$.

Maybe this picture can clear your ideas (the integration of the whole curve of course lead to 1, so you can use it to make additions/subtractions between areas):

[image: standard normal distribution integration example]

Comment: Well, I'm mostly aware of all that you've said. It's just that 'less' for part b) of the question was actually missing. writing the probability using the addition rule yields one.

Comment: I have added a part to the answer. Basically, if you want values that differ by "less" than 0.52 sigma you just have to consider internal values instead of external ones. Let me know if it's clear to you

Comment: Yes, that's helped me figure out where did I go wrong, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Taking (a) as an example, the proportion can be written as $$\mathbb P(X-\mu >1.3\sigma )+\mathbb P(X-\mu <-1.3\sigma)=1-\mathbb P(-1.3\sigma <X-\mu <1.3\sigma)$$ $$=1-\mathbb P(\mu -1.3\sigma <X<\mu +1.3\sigma)=1-\mathbb P\left(\frac{\mu -1.3\sigma -\mu}{\sigma}<Z<\frac{\mu +1.3\sigma-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$ $$=1-\mathbb P(-1.3<Z<1.3)$$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Using a normal distribution table or a calculator yields a probability of $1-0.8064=0.1936$.